Linking number of irregular curves
Let $f,g \colon S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$ be two continuous functions (not necessarily embeddings) whose images are disjoint. We define the linking number of these closed curves to be
$$
L(f,g) = \text{deg}(H_{(f,g)},S^1 \times S^1,S^2),
$$
where the function $H_{(f,g)}\colon S^1 \times S^1 \to S^2$ is given by
$$
H_{(f,g)}(u,v) = \frac{f(u) - g(v)}{|f(u) - g(v)|}.
$$
According to this post, if $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently regular, i.e. if $\text{Im}\, f = \partial M$ for some smooth embedded manifold $M$ of dimension $2$ and if $\text{Im}\, g$ intersects $M$ finitely many times, then the linking number (up to sign) is the number of times $\text{Im}\, g$ goes through $M$ in one direction minus the number of times it goes through $M$ in the opposite direction.

Does the same statement continue to hold when $f$ and $g$ are both less regular?

In order to generalize $\text{Im}\, f = \partial M$ of a less regular $f$, let's assume that $f$ is a planar curve, i.e.
$$
f(u) = (f^1(u), f^2(u), 0)
$$
for some continuous functions $f^1,f^2\colon S^1 \to \Bbb R$ (we allow $f$ to self-intersect). As for $g$, we shall keep it simple and assume that it intersects the plane $z=0$ only twice. In particular, we let
$$
g(v) = (g^1(v), g^2(v), g^3(v) ),
$$
where each $g^i\colon S^1 \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $g^3$ satisfies $g^3(0) = g^3(\pi) = 0$, $g^3$ is strictly increasing on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and strictly decreasing on $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ (e.g. $g(v) = \sin(v) )$, where we identify $S^1$ with its angular parametrization $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. Note that $g$ may intersect itself outside the plane $z=0$. The curve $f$ now wraps around the points $g(0)$ and $g(\pi)$ since it is planar.
Under these assumptions, it seems plausible that we have
$$
L(f,g) = \text{deg}(f, S^1, g(0) ) - \text{deg}(f, S^1, g(\pi) ),
$$
at least up to sign.

Is this formula well-known? If yes, could you please provide a reference to it?

This equivalence seems to be known at least for more regular curves, e.g. the definition of the linking number I am using here corresponds to definition (6) of the linking number in Rolfsen's "Knots and Links" page 133, while the formula above seems related to definition (5) on the same page. However, Rolfsen only discuss polygonal curves there.

You can always do the following: approximate $f, g$ by smooth loops and then use whatever the definition in the smooth case you like. In your particular setting, the result will coincide with the interpretation that you gave. But your setting is unnecessarily restrictive and I doubt it appears anywhere in the literature. You can also think it terms of topological transversality (satisfied in your case).

@MoisheKohan That is a very helpful comment, thank you. My background is in analysis of PDE, so I know very little about this topic. I formulated the question in this way because I'm mostly familiar with just the Brouwer degree, but not the algebraic topology side of it. Could you please recommend me a book or an article that contains some results that would imply the statement I am after?

I do not have a reference, but I can give a proof (along the lines of my first comment).

@MoisheKohan That sounds great, thanks!

Let $M$ be an oriented (topological) $m$-manifold, $N\subset M$ an oriented locally flat $n$-dimenso0nal submanifold, $K$ a $k$-dimensional manifold, possibly with boundary. For simplicity, I will assume that $\dim M= \dim N + \dim K$ and $K$ is compact. One says that a continuous map $f: K\to M$ is transversal to $L$ if $E=f^{-1}(K\cap N)$ is a finite  subset disjoint from $\partial K$ and that for for every $x\in E$ there exists neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $f(x)$ in $K$ and $M$ respectively such that the following holds. There exists a   homeomorphism $\psi: V\to \mathbb R^m$ such that $f$ is 1-1 on $U$, $f(U)\subset V$ and
$$
\psi(N\cap V)=\mathbb R^{n} \times \{0\},  
$$
$$
\psi(f(U))=\{0\} \times \mathbb R^{k}.   
$$
In the smooth setting, this property follows from the usual  transversality (but is weaker). Once you have this setting, you can define the oriented intersection number $I(N, f)$ exactly as in the smooth case, by counting the points of $E$ with $\pm$ sign according to the local orientations.
In your case, $M=\mathbb R^3$, $N$ is the image of $g$, $K$ is the 2-dimensional disk $D$, $f$ is an extension of your map $f$ to $D$, such that $f(D)\subset \mathbb R^2$, $f$ is smooth away from $\partial D$ and $f$ is transversal to $P=N\cap \mathbb R^2$ (as a map $D\to \mathbb R^2$). Here $P$ is oriented with orientation induced from $N$. Now, if I were to compute the oriented  intersection number $I(P, f)$ between $f: D\to \mathbb R^2$ and $P$, I would get exactly the difference of the two degrees as in your question. This number is the same as $I(N, f)$. It is the same as the linking number $L(N, f|_{\partial D})$ because $I(N, f)$ is preserved by small perturbations of $f$ and $N$ preserving  transversality and because the linking number can be computed as a suitable oriented intersection number in the smooth setting.

Very nice, thank you. May I ask which book(s) can I read more about the stuff you used here? I would assume these are somewhat standard results in algebraic topology or differential geometry, but I am just not familiar with the subjects. In particular, I would like to read more about transversality and how the intersection number is stable under small perturbations.

@BigbearZzz: In the smooth setting I would recommend the book by Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology." I am not sure if there is any textbook treatment of topological transversality.

That is fine. As long as the book covers everything you wrote in the answer so that I can fill in the details, then I am happy with it. Thank you for the recommendation. If there is any other interesting book on this subject, I'd be happy to learn about them as well.

May I ask one more question? How can we prove that an extension of $f$ to $D$ such that $f\colon D\to \Bbb R^2$ is transversal to $P$ exists? Could you please elaborate a bit more on this step?
